# Linking to "PayPal Donate" in your About Me?

Tags: discussion, users

I just viewed a user profile and saw a direct link to donate money to them via PayPal in their **About Me** section:

[image]

I guess it's within their profile where you can link to external resources like blogs/personal websites, but I've never seen this before, so I wondered if it's acceptable?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be acceptable?

Comment: I wasn't sure, hence I'm asking

Comment: Somewhat related: [Offering actual money as a bounty?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25615/168333) .

Comment: A discussion about this on Meta.SE: ["Is it acceptable to solicit money on a user profile?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190877/is-it-acceptable-to-solicit-money-on-a-user-profile)

Comment: Nice. But how do you do it? :)

Comment: A side note to this... I knew someone once who offered $500 to someone who could solve a rather complicated domain-specific question, in the comment space for when a bounty is added.  Nobody seriously took them up on it.  I was once stuck on a problem and my wife jokingly said, "tell them I'll make them cupcakes if they help you with the problem", so I added that to my bounty post.  Within seconds, I had 5 answers and one guy happened to live across town so I did deliver a couple dozen cupcakes for the effort.

Comment: Pretty sure I recognize that particular redaction.

Comment: @Brad so instead of money I should offer cupcakes, noted.

Comment: @Brad: I tried a similar thing for all of my questions. Now I am overweighted.

Comment: It can't be any worse than using a picture of a woman in a bikini and then asking for upvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1090562/salvador-dali.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

While putting affiliate (or donate) links in posts is a definite no-no, doing so in the user profile is okay.

In fact, except for some egregious anti-social behaviors (offensive usernames, avatars, or "about me" text) it's rare for Moderators to bother with user profiles.

(More information at this [answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/31478/262755).)

There's also [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190878/262755):

> No one is making you give that user money.
>
> As long as it is not against the [Terms of Service](https://stackexchange.com/legal), anything goes on
> personal user profiles.

Now, of course, if someone starts leaving comments like "if my answer really helped you, please consider using the 'Donate' button on my user profile", that would be too much.

Answer (score 7):

I think it is rather acceptable as I can't really think of a scenario when you are forced to pay real money for help within the SE.

The internal mechanism allows you to upvote, offer bounty, accept answer to reward an answerer - no real money is ever involved with the internal model.

If someone has helped you enough that you would like to pay them real money then it is completely your call. If they explicitly expose their identity in their "About Me" and are happy to accept real money for their contributions then feel free to make them but exclude SE from any inconvenience you may encounter.

You are not in any way encouraged or forced by SE to pay anyone real money for help received on the *.SE sites.