# Should users be allowed to request donations in the comments under their answers?

Tags: discussion, comments

I recently came across a post where a user requested a donation in the comments after they provided the accepted answer.

Here is the exact comment and context.

[image]

I have attempted to redact critical parts of the answer to decrease the likelihood of being able to easily find it, although I am sure the industrious among you will have no trouble.

I found these Meta discussions which seem to be relevant but do not directly address the issue:

- [Linking to PayPal Donate in Your About Me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265206/linking-to-paypal-donate-in-your-about-me)
- [Is It Acceptable to Solicit Money on a User Profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190877/is-it-acceptable-to-solicit-money-on-a-user-profile)

I attempted a brief review of the [Terms of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) but could not find a relevant section.

**Question**

Are users (or should users be) allowed to request donations in the comments?

**Clarification**

My question is not "can I flag this comment as no longer needed?", which is in my opinion the correct course of action here for multiple reasons, but rather "is the behavior allowed?". By the time the comment is moderated (or indeed even seen by me), the opportunity for solicitation has already been gained.

The [suggested duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265206/linking-to-paypal-donate-in-your-about-me), which was included in the original question, does not address the question. This is because this question focuses on direct solicitation content in questions and answers rather than indirectly in user profiles.

Comment: Well, the answer is quite easy: What are coments for? To suggest improvements or to request clarifications. Asking for money is neither, so not acceptable for a comment. Just flag it.

Comment: he also did this a lot of time (at least for the ones I found that aren't delete yet). Flagged the comment

Comment: No, users shouldn't be allowed to do this in comments. If my comment is helpful, please consider sending me some money. The more the better.

Comment: Flag, flag, flag. NLN is your friend. If you enjoyed flagging, please consider [buying me a coffee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGVBtKtGfds). Might also be worth checking if the user has left more comments like that - if they have, a mod flag might be necessary (though they might already know now that you've posted on meta).

Comment: @IanCampbell That profile seems to be repeating the same comment in another post as well

Comment: Interesting that it's apparently been assumed that such solicitations are for self-promotion or gain. Does the disapproval extend to suggesting that an appreciative recipient of advice might consider a contribution to a particular charity or non-profit organisation in which the responder has an interest?

Comment: @Magoo Interesting question. Have you observed that behavior in the past?

Comment: @IanCampbell No, but when a comment like `This code literally saved we months of work` is made, I'm sore tempted to make such a suggestion.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Generally speaking, this falls under [self promotion](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). You can do that in your profile, but asking for it directly in Q&A isn't kosher. The reward for good and useful answers is upvotes and accepts, not donated money.

Your response should be:

- If a user has made just one comment, please flag the comment. Comments like that aren't useful or in keeping with the intended purpose of comments, and all mods will delete them.
- If a user has posted this in their answer, please raise a custom moderator flag on the answer itself. Don't edit it out, because we need to see it to deal with it.
- If there's a pattern of comments, arbitrarily select one of the posts with such comments and raise a custom moderator flag on that post. Use the textbox provided to point out the pattern you've seen.

  (If you *think* you've seen a pattern of this behavior from a particular user, raising a flag on the post is important. This is because moderators handle comment flags in isolation; we wouldn't see the larger context. If you want us to do a more thorough investigation, looking at the user's other comments, including deleted ones, and possibly reach out to them to put a stop to the behavior, then you need to raise a custom flag on a question/answer.)

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, how would I know if the user has done it before? I cannot see their deleted comments.

Comment: @IanCampbell We don't expect you to look back through their comments. But if you've seen it elsewhere, mod flagging so we can take a look is appropriate. Remember, most comment flags are dealt with in isolation. Knowing there's a pattern means we can take more decisive action.

Comment: Not sure how effective this is. By the time the comments are dealt with, the OP(s) would have already read and (for those who want to donate) donated anyway.

Comment: @user202729 Sure they might get one or two donations that way. But if they continue to violate the rules after being explicitly warned by a moderator they probably don't have a bright future at SO ahead of them, so not a big problem.

Comment: When you say it "isn't kosher", you mean it in the same line as it's "heretical", as in, counter nature?

Comment: @Clockwork When someone uses "kosher" outside of food being prepared in line with Jewish custom, it is slang for "OK". So Machavity is saying it isn't OK/permitted.

Comment: "Kosher" derives from a Hebrew word meaning "fit" or "proper". So in the context of food, it means "fit to eat". If it's not kosher ... not fit to eat ... it's unacceptable, and that's the sense it's used outside the context of food. Whether eating non-kosher food is heresy ... I don't know.

Comment: It's used colloquially to mean "It's not *really* bad, but we frown upon you doing it". In this case, we probably wouldn't suspend the user outright, but we would send them a private message to let them know not to do that again.

Comment: Why shouldn't I edit it out of an answer? You can see the history of editing and I don't see it fit in the answer until a mod takes action on it...

Comment: @meJustAndrew First, by merely removing the problem parts, you potentially confuse the user. This can spark edit fights and harsh commentary, creating still more problems. Second, it's really easy for mods to miss that it's been edited (remember, we get about 1-2k flags **per day**). This is where you get errant declines.

Comment: A small clarification about what I meant, just in case: when I was speaking of "heresy", it was not directly linked to whether or not something is "kosher". I was making a very poor reference to the fact that, in the IT environment in which I evolved, we are used to qualifying "kosher" what is "good in nature". But then, on the other hand, when we are doing some mysterious black magic hack, then it's "heresy".

Comment: @Machavity what about if it is rep that we are asking for. For example, is it okay for a user to ask for a bounty in order to answer a question?

Comment: The self promotion article linked in this answer does not address this issue at all, nor explain why it "isn't kosher". The article says: "If the _only_ reason you're here is to sell something or drive traffic to your site, then please avoid posting answers" but whether someone is _only_ here for donations seems like a judgement call to be made on a case-by-case basis. How did you draw the conclusions in this answer from the article?

Comment: @jtbandes There's a big difference between having a tip jar on the counter vs shaking it in the face of every customer. Do you really want comments to be a place where people actively ask people for tips? `If you respond only to questions where the answer can be something you're selling, they'll assume you're just here to sell.` isn't a huge leap in applying to comments.

Comment: Sure. But that paragraph is phrased as "don't do this… **too much**". I don't imagine anyone here disagrees that doing it constantly would constitute spam, especially if it's clear that money is the poster's primary motivation. When someone has hundreds of good answers and adds an unobtrusive solicitation once in a while, isn't that different?

Comment: depends on the person. I tend to lean toward implicitly seeing the answer negatively after seeing such a comment. soliciting donations on only a few answers, because doing it on all of them would attract attention, is just a form of skirting under the radar because you know you can even though you know you're doing something people disapprove of.

Answer (score 32):

If the appropriate action in the case of repeat solicitation is to raise a flag on a user's post "in need of moderator intervention" as suggested by @Machavity in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403859/), it may be helpful to review a user's comment history.

The comment history may be accessed by opening their profile.

Then click <kbd>Activity</kbd> ➪ <kbd>All actions</kbd> ➪ <kbd>Comments</kbd>

[image: Image of user profile annotated to show suspicious links]
<sub>Note: I have created these fictitious comments outside of the site.</sub>

This will only show the user's visible comments, and thus cannot be fully accurate. Nonetheless, it could be used as a way to confirm a recollection.

Comment: I like that you included that "Note" in there, lest some moderator hastily destroys your account for self-promotion in the comments. :-)

Comment: You can just use the Inspector to modify styles and/or HTML on the fly. That skips the step of having to save a copy to the hard drive, and you can see the changes immediately.

Answer (score 15):

I fully believe soliciting donations in any way, shape or form has absolutely no place on Stack Overflow. I would go so far as to say even doing so in your profile is unacceptable. It would quickly reduce the platform to nothing but spam. It would do so in the following way:

- It would encourage people to contribute more low quality answers in the hopes that perhaps their answer gets chosen. It is already a big issue on Stack Overflow if you ask me.
- It would create more unnecessary comments on answers, also already an issue on Stack Overflow.
- It could also completely derail discussions in comments.
- I believe it may create somewhat of a liability to Stack Overflow as they are now facilitating financial transactions.
- It would also encourage link only self promotional answers. It is already a big problem on Stack Overflow.

So in summary, I believe that soliciting donations is a hard line that needs to be drawn. The fact this is even in debate highlights the fact that Stack Overflow needs to make a statement on this and put it in the rules.

As a community, we owe it to ourselves to ensure the quality and purpose of Stack Overflow is upheld. That is, to provide useful information bereft of useless spam or clutter.

*Edit due to comments*

I guess I can concede that perhaps it might be a bit of a stretch to bar it from user profiles due to the arguments provided. Ultimately it's easier for SO to take action and edit a users profile in the event of abuse, versus having to blanket remove offending material from all of the users comments.

Comment: I absolutely agree. You're supposed to volunteer your time to participate. If you don't want to volunteer, don't do it. As simple as that.

Comment: Only the SO company is permitted to make money from users' contributions.

Comment: Lots of people link to their consultancy businesses in their profile - it's arguably a big part of what the profile link is for. I agree that it's spammy for comments but I can't bring myself to have a moral problem with links on profiles

Comment: I disagree. While I think this has absolutely no point in answers or comments, having a donation link in a users profile (and obviously without mentioning this in comments or answers!) seems perfectly fine to me. If someone takes the effort to check out a user's profile, stumbles upon it and acts on their own where's the problem? (If anything you encourage users to post high quality answers to increase their chances). Also if we're against this, we should presumably also warn Jon Skeet about the self promoting link to his book on his profile.

Comment: However, [it is acceptable in profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31504/rules-for-profiles).

Comment: @Teemu Linking to a question thread does not give it any sort of validity. The only way to confirm it would be a direct link to SO's declaration pertaining to it.

Comment: While I totally agree on the "don't ASK for donations" Part, especially as it does not help the topic, I'd dig a microtransaction system (best built into SO) giving me a 1-click method to gift someone that helped me. (I see the organizational and legal problems that would bring though.)

Comment: @Hybridwebdev No? It's a part of the official SE Moderator FAQ.

Comment: As somebody who has clicked to view the profile of somebody who really helped me out, saw that they had a buymeacoffee link, and bought them a coffee, I disagree. It was a nice way to show my appreciation above and beyond a few worthless karma points

Answer (score 4):

Let's call the donation "pay a coffee", I like the term.

I believe this is a dangerous path. Once the author of an answer is able to "request a coffee", it won't be long before users ask for functionality that allows them to ask the OP to "pay a coffee" if the OP wants to receive an answer from them.

Once this happens most people would not answer just for reputation, and would instead start a "bounty" where questions are answered faster when the OP pays something. And maybe some important questions would be ignored just because they didn't offer anything with monetary value.

It's pleasant to think about answering a question, and the result being that the OP is so happy that they decide to pay you something in return, but this would break the system of sharing knowledge that this forum has.

Comment: Conversely, we don't want to encourage people to drink too much coffee.  (Perhaps StackOverflow needs mandatory drug testing.  We wouldn't want "reputation drug cheats": people who drink lots of coffee so that they can stay up all night earning reputation by doing other peoples' homework :-) )

Comment: Whether people are allowed to request a coffee, feel free to disapprove, but the argument "because then the site will change and you will have to buy coffee to get an answer" is a slippery slope fallacy. If this site were to start charging money for answers, it wouldn't be a consequence of letting people post "buy me a coffee" links.

Comment: @khelwood I have no problem with people requesting it in the comments after answering it. I just used the term "Buy me a coffee" because I think is more personal than "Pay me", and I like it. I just don't feel that would be good for the community as a whole the functionality to me a native of SOF.