# Is there a program where I can pay back the contributors?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I'm super grateful for the marvelous help that Stack Overflow's community has been to my progress and to solve issues that I would otherwise have been stuck on.

Is there a program on Stack Overflow for me to contribute a chosen monthly amount that gets redistributed to questions and answers that I upvote?

Comment: Tangentially related about general stance on donation info in profiles (one of the ways you can thank contributors materially if you really want to): [Linking to "PayPal Donate" in your About Me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265206/11407695)

Comment: In both case, yes, both of your links tangentially answer my question. For the first, my main problem is that my time is scarce. I am happy to contribute further whenever I have the time, but I want to contribute more, and time is a hard limit for me. For the second, I knew the answer would come up - I'm more interested in contributing globally, rather than giving money directly to specific individuals. Once again, I think that time wise it is unreasonable to pay every contributor I receive help from manually.